# Ionic input type="number" allows multiple decimal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic input type number allows user to enter multiple decimal points which gives **NaN**. How it can be restricted to enter only one decimal point?

```
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Number Input"></ion-input>
```

I am expecting 21.21 but it also allows me to enter 21..21.21.12..12 which is NAN

Comment: Information is insufficient. Clearly mention what is your expected output. Also enter some current inputs.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question. If I change ion-input to input then it does not show number keypad in mobile.

Comment: ^^ ok i re opened it

Comment: this will satisfy your condition try this pattern ^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$

Comment: use directive on input to restrict only one decimal in the field.